# Generating random double vectors with <random> and a function

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I've written the following function to generate a random vector of doubles:

```
void getrands(vector<double> *x)
{
  int N=(*x).size();
  uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(0.0,1.0);
  mt19937 re(time(NULL));
  auto generator = bind(unif,re);
  generate_n((*x).begin(),N,generator);
}
```

In my main() program, if I try to call this function on several vectors (say I want to generate 10 random vectors) I end up with all my vectors having the same random numbers in them, because not enough time has elapsed to get a good re-seed. What is a better way to do this? Should I create a random array then convert it to vectors? I'm used to matlab where I can just call X=rand(n,m)...

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better way would be to seed your random number generator using [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device).

```
mt19937 re(std::random_device{}());
```

And you should probably pass the RNG as an argument to the function, rather than create a new instance every iteration.

Also, be aware that `std::bind` copies its arguments, so you may want to wrap the RNG in `std::ref` before passing it as an argument to `bind`.

---

I'd rewrite your function as

```
template<typename Generator>
void getrands(vector<double>& x, Generator& gen, unsigned num)
{
  generate_n(std::back_inserter(x), num, std::ref(gen));
}
```

And call it as

```
uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(0.0,1.0);
mt19937 re(std::random_device{}());
auto generator = bind(unif, std::ref(re));

vector<double> vs;

getrands(vs, generator, 10);
```

This allows you to reuse the same RNG, you don't need to set the vector to the correct size before calling the function and you can add values to the vector if needed.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52fcf2c89916e770)

Comment: Ah, this seems to work. I'm just leaning c++11 so this is all new to me. Could you expand a bit/give a reference on your last comment re:bind?

Comment: @icurays1 `bind` will make a copy of its argument(s), so let's say you create a second bind expression `auto generator2 = bind(unif,re);`, you'll see that invoking both `generator` and `generator2` will yield an identical sequence of results. If you changed your bind expression to `auto generator = bind(unif, ref(re));` a copy of the RNG would no longer be made, and `generator` and `generator2` would yield distinct sequences.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I've tried passing my RNG re as a variable and I'm back to getting duplicates...any thoughts why that is? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @icurays1 The function parameter needs to be a reference type. For instance, `void foo(mt19937& rng)`, not `void foo(mt19937 rng)`. Take a look at the link I posted, it contains example usage.

Comment: Got it - everything is working great now, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should move out the definition for the `std::mt19937` into the global scope so that it gets initialized only once. Random number generation is one of the rare cases where a global variable makes more sense. Besides, the best practice for seeding is to use `std::random_device` rather than the current time.

Comment: I'm a bit confused where I should move it - outside my functions, as a const...?  (I'm still getting used to c++)

Comment: @icurays1: Do you know the concept of *global variables* in C/C++?

Comment: Yes, in principle. When I move my mt19937 re(...) declaration outside my functions I get the duplicate behavior again (even with the random_device seed method)

Comment: @icurays1: That's strange. Can you post a minimal compilable code that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Ah, never mind - not sure why it wasn't working but it is now!